# How to exit tmux's prefix mode after switching pane

Tags: tmux

I switch panes often and when I press ctrl-a-right I move the the right. Then if I start typing "vim", the 'v' causes a ctrl-a-v (split vertically) to be issued, but I don't want this. How do I make tmux realize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to remove `-r` in `.tmux.conf` on the `split-window` options. Removing `-r` causes repeats to be disabled.

from

```
bind -r v split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

to

```
bind v split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .tmux.conf, add

```
bind Up    select-pane -U
bind Down  select-pane -D
bind Left  select-pane -L
bind Right select-pane -R
```

or if you're using vim directions,

```
bind k select-pane -U
bind j select-pane -D
bind h select-pane -L
bind l select-pane -R
```

as detailed in this post: https://superuser.com/a/1273727